# Importing large Bson file to mongo db in raspberry pi

Tags: mongodb, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, bson

I am trying to import a very large BSON file (15Gb) to mongodb. I am using a raspberry pi 3b+ (it has a 1Gb of ram).

The problem I am running to is that when I execute the mongorestore command to import the bson, the process is killed.
I have tried to add swap using a usb (6Gb added) but the problem persists, the error displayed is related to lack of ram.
Executing the command in a Ubuntu Virtual Machine with 8Gb ram shows no problem.

Thanks

Comment: what about importing all documents from ubuntu virtual machine on rpi via network

Comment: What do you mean? How is it done?